# Check if the component action gets called in an integration test

Tags: javascript, ember.js, integration-testing

I have the following simple component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions:{
    someAction(){
      //...
    }
  }
});
```

What should I do(in an integration test) if I want to check if this action gets called in the corresponding `hbs` file?

Comment: If your action is a classic action you can subsribe to events in integrations tests `this.on('someAction', function() { assert.ok(true, 'It gets called'); });` give this [article](https://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/ember-component-integration-tests/) a read.

Comment: @Kitler, what do you mean by "classic action"? Given the code above and trying to use your approach I don't get it(the delegate passed to `on`) called

Answer (score 1):

I'm using following code for integration tests of component

```
assert.expect(numberOfAssertionsInYourTest)

this.set('onClick', () => {
  assert.ok(true, 'Closure action after click on item was executed');
});

this.render(hbs`{{menu-item title='Hello' onClickAction=(action onClick)}}`);

this.$('.menu-item').click()
```

The second option is to test results of your actions. I use this option mostly for actions that are implemented in components (e.g. collapse/expand)

Comment: Could you please show what `onClickAction` is  in your component?

Comment: Don't forget to add an `assert.expect(numberOfAssertionsInYourTest)` so the test fails if the action isn't called

Comment: In this case, 'onClickAction' is just what you see. Closure actions are defined outside of component scope. In my case (single-page app), it send information to controller about which menu item was selected so it is possible to re-render the rest of page.

Comment: @Kitler - thansk, I have added it to a response

Comment: @Marek, if it is all to `onClickAction` than who and how is calling it? It certainly should be generated somehow. Also, if you can see in my question I have an action defined which I'd like to test if it is called. Could you please show me a complete example which show how it can be done?

Comment: in the component itself template (<span onclick='{{action onSelect}}')> ...) I use an action defined inside component which calls this.attrs.onClickAction().

Comment: If you want to test an existing action then I would either test it in similar way to check if it is action is executed or not - and afterwards test action with unit test. OR if you can measure success of your action, just check if result is what you expect. That way you just click on the right place and with jQuery you can test results.

Comment: @Marek, thanks for the answer but it is not what I need. What you are using is described in the Ember documentation in the component testing part. What I need is something different: I need exactly what is written in the question, nothing else. No workarounds. If it is not possible — fine, but I'd like to know that and why is that so.